# can't Specify an audio profile using Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 in c#

Tags: c#, google-text-to-speech

I'm trying to convert Text To audio using  Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1. it works fine but I do not know how can I Specify an audio profile to use using c# while I found code in Node.js and python But Not anything in c# this is my code

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            List<Word> lst = IntialData();

            System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"C:\Users\Admin\TextToSpeechApiDemo\key.json");


            var client = TextToSpeechClient.Create();
           
            // The input to be synthesized, can be provided as text or SSML.

            foreach (Word item in lst)
            {
                var input = new SynthesisInput
                {
                    Text = item.Name,
                    
                  
                };
          
                // Build the voice request.
                var voiceSelection = new VoiceSelectionParams
                {
                    LanguageCode = "ar",
                    //SsmlGender = SsmlVoiceGender.Female,
                
                    Name = "ar-XA-Wavenet-A"
                };

                // Specify the type of audio file.
                var audioConfig = new AudioConfig
                {
                    AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                    
                    




                }; 
          

                    // Perform the text-to-speech request.
                    var response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(input, voiceSelection, audioConfig);

                // Write the response to the output file.
                using (var output = File.Create(@"E:\Noursound\sim\ar-XA-Wavenet-A\" + item.Id.ToString() + ".wav"))
                {

                    response.AudioContent.WriteTo(output);

                }

            }
            
           
        }
```

I found this code in python he set **effects_profile_id**

```
audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3,
        effects_profile_id=[effects_profile_id],
```

How can i do that using c#

Comment: Unfortunately `EffectsProfileId` is only available in [STT V1Beta1](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1Beta1/latest/Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1Beta1.AudioConfig#Google_Cloud_TextToSpeech_V1Beta1_AudioConfig_EffectsProfileId) and it is set as read only thus a value cannot be assigned to `EffectsProfileId`. What I could suggest is to [file an issue in GCP Text To Speech github repository](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues).

Comment: Posting the created git issue https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/7400 for reference.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in the version on the NuGet package i used 1.0.0-beta01 , and it's not have the  EffectsProfileId property but after update it to version  to Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1 version 2.3.0 i found the property.

```
using Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new AudioConfig
        {
            AudioEncoding = AudioEncoding.Mp3,
            EffectsProfileId = { "your profile ID" }
        };
    }
}
```

i created git issue for that on github Here's [a link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/7400)!